# Problem with message_filter inizialization

Tags: ros, node-handle, callback, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to write a C++ class containing message_filters as members.

In the [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28C.2B-.2B-.29) they are declared in this way:

```
message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt32> sub(nh, "my_topic", 1);
sub.registerCallback(myCallback);
```

while for using them in a class I found that this could be a way:

```
class DBCreator
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    message_filters::Subscriber<capygroovy::Ticks> ticks_sub_;
   
public:
    DBCreator()
    {
        ticks_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("/ticks",1,&DBCreator::ticksCallback,this);
```

but I get this error:

> /opt/ros/groovy/include/message_filters/subscriber.h:96:
> note:   no known conversion for
> argument 1 from ‘ros::Subscriber’ to
> 'const message_filters::Subscriber< capygroovy::Ticks_< std::allocator < void > > >&'

that is, ticks_sub_ should be a `ros::Subscriber` object.

I'm not very familiar with this topic so I'd be glad if someone could help me understand how to initialize this object inside the class!!!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173090/problem-with-message_filter-inizialization/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2014-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of using the default subscriber created from a ros NodeHandle, you should be creating message_filters::Subscriber instances as described in the [C++ example](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28C.2B-.2B-.29) on the wiki.

In your case, this could look like:

```
DBCreator() {
    ticks_sub_ = message_filters::Subscriber<capygroovy::Ticks>(nh_, "/ticks", 1);
    ticks_sub_.registerCallback(&DBCreator::ticksCallback,this);
}
```

Or you can use the C++ member initializer syntax:

```
DBCreator() : ticks_sub_(nh_, "/ticks", 1) {
        ticks_sub_.registerCallback(&DBCreator::ticksCallback,this);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2014-06-09**:
The first example doesn't work, but the second does and I also prefer it. Thanks a lot for your help!!!